# PYTHON - MAX TCP CONNECTIONS?

Tags: python, tcp, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the practical / hard limit on socket connections per server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391847/what-is-the-practical-hard-limit-on-socket-connections-per-server)

When I hit about 480 TCP connections, it doesn't accept + connections.
Where it is the max of TCP connections?
Windows 2008..

Comment: A very quick Google search indicates that a single IP address can support well over 60000 active connections. See e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951764

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Windows 2008 edition, Web and Foundation editions have connection limits while Standard, Enterprise, and Datacenter do not.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Ow, mine is web... Can't I change the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not limit connections.  It is controlled/limited by the underlying operating system and network stack.

However, if you are working directly with python's `socket` module, you can adjust some parameters using `socket.setsockopt(level, optname, value)` before you bind to the port.

you can also tweak windows registry settings to enable more concurrent connections.
see:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.12.network.aspx

the `TcpNumConnections`, `MaxUserPort`,and `EnableConnectionRateLimiting` tcp settings are good places to start.